# Failed to bootstrap simple manager by cloudify-cli@4.0.1 which is installed by rpm package builded myself

Tags: cloudify

I build a rpm package for the cloudify-cli source code with tag 4.0.1 by running command "rpmbuild -bb build.spec". The rpm package was builded and installed successfully even though the rpm package is smaller than the rpm package downloaded from Cloudify.co.

I bootstrap a simple manager with the installed cloudify-cli.
During the bootstrapping process, the log requires me to be in a virtual environment to install plugin, so i go into a virtual environment and bootstrap a simple manager again. Then the log shows me an error was raised, like this:
[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSsFG.jpg)

Can you help me to solve this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your RPM lacks some packages that are included in Cloudify RPMs

You should add to the RPM or install manually the following packages:

cloudify-rest-client

cloudify-dsl-parser

cloudify-plugins-common

cloudify-script-plugin

Comment: Thanks for your answering. But these packages were all installed.